# android error trying to write to external SD

Tags: android

I am trying to write a jpg image to the external SD card. However, I am getting System.err `FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/test.images/temp/savedImage (no such file or directory)`. Creating the directory also seems to fail and gives a `false` in LogCat and I also cannot see the folder when looking on my SD card.

My code is as follows:

```
if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {   
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.images/temp");
        try {
            if(!folder.exists()){
                boolean dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.images/temp").mkdir();
                Log.v("creating directory", Boolean.toString(dir));
            }
            File imageOutputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.images/temp", "savedImage");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageOutputFile);
            Image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

I have permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
 in the manifest and have cleaned and rebuilt.

Comment: ` File imageOutputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.images/temp/", "savedImage.jpg");`

Answer (score 1):

> Use mkdirs() instead of mkdir().

Guido posted a solution that works for me in the comment. I am going to repeat it just to make sure it can be an answer.